# How do I connect an internal SATA drive to Mini-SAS?

Tags: ssd, mac-pro, sata

I have a SATA III SSD which I would like to connect to an ATTO technologies' SATA II card in my Mac Pro. The SSD uses the typical internal SATA interface while the ATTO card uses Mini-SAS both internally and externally.

What do I need to plug the SSD into the ATTO card? I'm assuming internal/external doesn't matter, and that I'd get the same speeds either way, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper cable:

http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Adaptec-Serial-Attached-SCSI-SAS-external-cable-1.6-ft/1217280.aspx

Details:

```
Interface Provided
  Connector Qty:         1
  Connector Type:        36 pin 4i Mini MultiLane SAS (SFF-8087)

Interface Required
  Connector Qty:         4
  Connector Type:        29 pin internal SAS (SFF-8482)
```